# turn off audio progressively on click

Tags: javascript, html, audio, volume

I have an engine song in autoplay and i want that when i click on my button the sound turn off "progressively" for get a fluid diminution of the volume and finish at 0.1 or 0.2 of the volume, someone have an idea ? 
This is my actual code:

```html
<audio autoplay>
   <source src="../audio/2445.mp3">
</audio>

<button>turn off</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure if this is right way to do it, you could do something like:

```
<audio autoplay id='aud'>
   <source src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/Ludwig_van_Beethoven_-_Symphonie_5_c-moll_-_1._Allegro_con_brio.ogg'>
</audio>

<button id='btn'>turn off</button>
```

JS:

```
var audio = document.getElementById('aud'), interval;
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = turnOff;
function turnOff(){
    if(audio && !audio.paused){
        interval = setInterval(function(){
            console.log('audio volume: ', audio.volume);
            if(!audio || audio.paused || audio.volume < 0.1){
                clearInterval(interval);
            }else{
                audio.volume -= .05; // change this value as per your liking
            }
        }, 200); // change this value as per your liking
    }
}
```

I guess a better way to do it might be with `web-audio`.

#### [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b0w2rqmp/)